# How does Python's website generate its online documentation?

Tags: python, directory, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

> Created using Sphinx 0.6.5.

I know Python's documentation uses `reStructuredText`, but it has different sections like `http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html` and `http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html`.

How do you do this in reStructuredText? Do you run `rst2html` in a bunch of directories, keeping its structure?

I know that it uses Sphinx (not rst2html directly as said by [Thomas Wouters in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856847/how-does-pythons-website-generate-its-online-documentation/2857216#2857216)), but how you should organize your rst structure with source code files in a repository so you have a full blown automated doc website?

Comment: Did you look at the source for the Python documentation?  http://svn.python.org/view/  It's quite clear how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Python documentation uses reST for its *markup*, but it generates the HTML using `sphinx`, not `rst2html` directly. The `sphinx` tool is what converts all the individual `.rst` files into multiple `.html` files. To see how the Python docs are generated, see http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Doc/Makefile

Answer (score 4):

I found the [sampledoc tutorial on the matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/sampledoc/) quite useful to get started with Sphinx.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [how to build Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html#building-doc) exactly.